# Download (only) OpenJDK and not install it

Tags: java

I do **not** wish to change my host's notion of what Java is, only download one or more JDKs including OpenJDK. I need to test and compare JDKs as part of a build system.

Just as I am able to download and then **not** install Oracle JDK with no problem, I need to download and **not** install a copy of open JDK. The website http://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html doesn't offer this possibility.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would be to download OpenJDK source code and build it. For 8, it basically boils down to cloning the right set of trees and then doing the regular build steps:

```
cd /path/to/where/you/cloned/jdk8u
mkdir build
bash ../configure # not ../configure because configure is not marked as executible
make all
```

Look under build/ and search for a j2sdk-image directory. That's your jdk:

```
cp -a build/images/j2sdk-image /location/where/i/put/my/jdks/
```

The distribution packages of OpenJDK often include various changes that make it not suitable for moving around (liked tweaked `RPATHs`). That said, if you are feeling up to the risk, you can do something like:

```
yum --download-only install 'java-1.8.0-openjdk*'
```

Now you have a bunch of RPMs. Extract them manually:

```
rpm2cpio ./name.of.rpm.x86_64.rpm | cpio -id
```

You should see `usr` and other fumnny looking directories in the current working directory. Go through the, find the OpenJDK dir and move it over to some other location. For example:

```
cp -a usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b16.fc24.x86_64/ /location/where/i/put/my/jdks/
```

Note that it's `usr/`, not `/usr/`. Strip non-`$ORIGIN` `RPATH`s if you see on any ELF files.

Something similar probably exists for Debian/Ubuntu, but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Why cant you just download openjdk like you can Oracle jdk, does openjdk only exist for Linux or is it available for Windows as well ?

Comment: OpenJDK project doesn't publish binaries, officially speaking. I have no idea why... It might be because the majority of contributors are from Oracle and they prefer people use the Oracle JDK (this is only me speculating). Others involved in OpenJDK project publish binaries. [Red Hat](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/hello-world/). [Adapt OpenJDK](http://adoptopenjdk.net/). [Azul](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu/).